# Batch-Renaming Movies using Regex

Tags: regex, batch-rename

I've been trying to rename some movie files using regular expressions, but so far I have been only marginally successful. The goal is to parse files like this:

```
2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-LiNG.mkv
```

And rename them Like this:

```
2001 A Space Odyssey (1968).mkv
```

I created the pattern: `^(.+)\.(\d{4}).+\.(mp4|avi|mkv)$`

With the output: `\1 (\2).\3`

Now, this works perfectly fine when I have movies with one-word titles, but when there is more than one word separated by a period, the regex fails to grab anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ooohh....I smell pirated stuff.... :P

Comment: why not just use a tool specifically designed for this, including external API integration for meta? an example that springs to mind is filebot http://www.filebot.net/  seems like you are reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern seems to work fine for me with that example filename and Perl as the regex engine:

```
$ echo '2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-LiNG.mkv' | 
    perl -npe 's/^(.+).(\d{4}).+.(mp4|avi|mkv)$/\1 (\2).\3/'

2001.A.Space.Odyssey (1968).mkv
```

The only thing I would change is to escape the `.`'s where you actually do want them to refer to a period and not a wildcard. In particular it's probably safe to assume the final period before the file extension is actually a period - I'm not sure about the one between the title and the year.

Answer (score 2):

I've spend several hours writing and fine-tuning a python script to do exactly this. One of the things I've found is that quite often it's not as black and white as handling a single file like this.

Note: This is python based, which will require tweaking if you're working in another language

Why I'm telling you this:

- Sometimes the file is poorly named, while the parent folder is named like you've indicated.
- Sometimes you'll get articles or roman numerals in the middle that should/shouldn't be uppercase
- You may want to move "The" to the end, as in ", The"
- Sometimes the date is missing
- In your particular example, your regex will have a hard time differentiating between 2001 and 1968.

In the end, you may find that breaking up your function into several chunks (or using matching) will help you strip it apart.

Here is a basic summary of what I've ended up using:

1: Set some global variables to allow for flexibility:

```
renamePattern = "%titlethe% %quality% (%year%).%ext%" 
articles = ['a', 'an', 'of', 'the', 'is', 'on', 'at', 'in', 'and']
roman = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XI', 'XII', 'XIII']
```

2: Check if the file has a valid name, otherwise go up and check the folder:

```
if (re.search(".+(108|72)0p?.+", folder) and re.search(".+(\s|\.)(19|20)[0-9][0-9](.*|(?!p))", folder)):
#appears to have a valid quality and date, return folder

elif (re.search(".+(108|72)0p?.+", file) and re.search(".+(\s|\.)(19|20)[0-9][0-9](.*|(?!p))", file)):
#appears to have a valid date and quality, return file

else:
#return None, which will fail the script
```

3: Do some magic

```
f = re.sub("\.", " ", file_string)
s = re.sub("\.", "", s)

if re.search("\%\w+\%", s):
    if re.search("titlethe", s):
        s = titleCase(f, articles)
        s = re.sub("\s(19|20)[0-9][0-9](.*|(?!p))$", "", s)
        s = re.sub("\s?(108|72)0p\s?", "", s, re.I)
        if re.search("^The\s", s):
            s = re.sub("^The\s", "", s) + ", The"
    elif re.search("thetitle", s):
        #do thetitle stuff
        s = titleCase(f, articles)
        s = re.sub("\s(19|20)[0-9][0-9](.*|(?!p))$", "", s)
        s = re.sub("\s?(108|720)p\s?", " ", s, re.I)
    elif re.search("quality", s):
        if re.search(".*1080p?.*", f, re.I):
            s = "1080p"
        elif re.search(".*720p?.*", f, re.I):
            s = "720p"
    elif re.search("year", s):
        p = re.compile(".+\s(?P<year>(19|20)[0-9][0-9])(.*|(?!p))")
        if p is not None:
            m = p.match(f)
            s = m.group('year')
    elif re.search("ext", s):
        s = getExt(file_name)
return re.sub("[ ]{2,}", " ", s)
```

Edit: In the end, if you actually just want the python script I've written, let me know and I'll post it on sourceforge or git.

Comment: I would love to see your whole script.

Comment: I know this is incredibly late to the game, but you may be interested in the script I've been developing over the last few years. It's been working well, so I haven't refactored in a while, but I am planning out a serious refactor, including a REST API to help with all sorts of utilities for this very problem. Btw, the regex I use is: `new_title = re.sub(r"[^\$#! | ^\w\d'\s]+", ' ', title).replace('_', ' ')` and a link to the script you'd be interested in is: https://github.com/blairg23/movie-file-fixer/blob/development/formatter.py

Comment: Ha, as am I. Mine is here now: https://github.com/brandonscript/fylm